# Conjecture about a famous trigonometric integral

Tags: improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification, pi, trigonometric-integrals

I don't know if this conjecture is well know but let me try it :

> > Let $f(x)$ be a continuous , differentiable function on $[0;+\infty[ $ with $f(x)\geq 0 \quad\forall x\geq 0$  and  such that :$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ then the equation $f(x)=x$ have at least one solution  on $[0;+\infty[ $.

I have tried to find counter-example like :
 $f(x)=x^n+y$ and it seems to work

$f(x)=x+\alpha e^{\beta}$ works too

I have not tried counter-example like :
$f(x)=x+ \sin^2(x)$ where we have an infinity of solution .

If it works maybe we can use power series of $h(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and make the substitution $f(x)=x+g(x)$  but I don't know what to do next .

Another idea is to use Lipschitzian maps but it becomes really difficult for me.

My question :

First I want to know : Is there a counter-example ?

Any helps is greatly appreciated .

Thanks a lot .

### Update:

Since :$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=0$$

We deduce that there is an $y\in [0;+\infty[$ such that :

$$\frac{\sin(f(y))}{f(y)}-\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=0$$

Or:
$$\frac{\sin(f(y))}{f(y)}=\frac{\sin(y)}{y}$$

Wich have as solution :$f(y)=y$

It is right ?